# How do I remove singe carriage returns while leaving double carriage returns intact?

Tags: regex, powershell, text, replace

I have an txt ebook which is formatted to 80 columns. This is quite incovenient on an ebook reader like Kindle because carriage returns break text in a quite random way. However I find double (and triple, quadruple, etc.) carriage returns convenient because they separate paragraphs. How do I remove these single (\r\n) carriage returns? Preferably in Powershell so I can make batch for many files.

Comment: How are having troubles finding single carriage returns, and not having problems finding double (or triple, quadruple) of them ?

Answer (score 1):

Use zero-width assertions (so-called lookaheads and lookbehinds) to ensure you're only removing line breaks that aren't surrounded by more line breaks:

```
(Get-Content path\to\ebook.txt -Raw) -replace '(?<!\r?\n)\r?\n(?!\r?\n)'
```

The negative lookbehind expression `(?<!\r?\n)` ensure no line breaks following immediately after another line break is replaced, and the negative lookahead expression `(?!\r?\n)` ensures no line breaks immediately followed by another is replaced.